# Error message when trying to open and access data from other excel documents using VBA. OK allows program to resume. How do I avoid this issue?

Tags: excel, vba, file, reference

I use the following code to open another workbook and pull data.

```
FileName = "F:\QA\CMM\CMM Job Results\2-08533R\Rev4\F103223\Excel Printouts\2- 08533R_Rev4_" & i & "1.xls"
Set arc(i) = Workbooks.Open(FileName, True, True)
```

When I do this, the file opens and the following error message appears:

> Unable to locate ReportINI sheet. Please make sure, ReportINI.xls is in the -xlstart- subdirectory of the -office- program.

This is caused by a macro in the workbook I'm trying to open. All of the workbooks I would like to pull data from have macros.

I want to access data from several Excel workbooks and reorganize it. Is there another way to access data from several unopened Excel workbooks without causing a script pause to answer this error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If macros in workbooks being opened by code are causing problems the execution of such macros can be disabled for the current macro session. This is similar to the setting in the Trust Center, but doesn't change that setting - it only changes it for the duration of code execution.

Use the following line of code before opening any workbooks:

```
Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
```

Comment: That was fast :-) Glad it helped!